# Importing two different classes from two modules with the same package path

Tags: java, maven, kotlin, module, dependencies

I have maven project that has main POM module, for example Main. Main contains two pom-modules: "core" and "app". "core" contains jar-module "A", "app" contains jar-module "B"
I have next classes:

1. app.B.src.main.java.di.AModule.kt //dependency injection module
2. app.B.src.main.java.domain.App.java //main app
3. core.A.src.main.java.domain.BModule.kt //another injections

When i import AModule.kt and BModule.kt into App.java, it looks like

```
import di.AModule;
import di.BModule;
```

Maven can't finish install-phase and says "Cannot find symbol" pointing to ***import AModule***, that is semantically closer to App.java

What should I do with pom-files or packages to fix this problem?

P.S. Also I have a problem that maven doesn't see ***core.A.src.test.java.SomethingTest.kt*** during test-phase

Comment: Where does `di.BModule` in the second import come from? You only mention a `di.AModule` (1.) and a `domain.BModule` (3.).

Comment: Did you declare `A` as a `<dependency>` in `B`'s POM?

Comment: @GeroldBroser core.A.src.main.java.di.BModule.kt*

Comment: Is `app.B.src.main.java.di`, etc. really your package structure?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your projects (according to what can be extracted from your question):

```
+- Main
   +- core
      +- src/main/java
      |  +- di
      |     +- AModule.kt
      +- target
      |  +- A.jar
      +- pom.xml ... <artifactId>A
   +- app
      +- src/main/java
      |  +- domain
      |     +- App.java
      |     +- BModule.kt
      +- target
      |  +- B.jar
      +- pom.xml ... <artifactId>B
```

Projects `A` and `B` are independent of each other. Being both a [`<module>`](https://svn.apache.org/repos/infra/websites/production/maven/content/pom.html#Aggregation) of `Main` just let you build them in one go (via building `Main`).

To be able to reference `AModule` in `App` you have to declare its JAR `A` as a `<dependency>` in `B`'s POM:

```xml
    ...
    <artifactId>B</artifactId>
    ...
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>...</groupId>
            <artifactId>A</artifactId>
            <version>...</version>
        </dependency>
    ...
```

The `<packaging>` type of projects that contain code, and should create an artifact, has to be [`jar`, `war`, etc.](https://svn.apache.org/repos/infra/websites/production/maven/content/pom.html#Maven_Coordinates), not `pom`.

It's also recommended to separate different source types like:

```
   ...
   +- app
   |  +- src/main
   |     +- java
   |     |  +- domain
   |     |     +- App.java
   |     +- kotlin
   |        +- domain
   |           +- BModule.kt
   ...
```

Comment: Want to correct your drawn structure:
**core** contains jar-packaging module  **A** that has _src...AModule_ and **core** is pom-packaging.
**app** contains jar-packaging **B** that has _src...BModule_ and _App_, and **app** is pom-packaging.

I declared dependency on whole **core**-module in _app/pom.xml_ and also declared dependency on **A**-module in _app/B/pom.xml_

Comment: @ShpilevojArsenij Code in projects with `<packaging>pom` is not compiled, tested, etc. and no artifact is created. This packaging type is only meant to be for parent projects which contain declarations for inheritance to (sub-)`<module>`s. Change the packaging type of `A` and `B` to `jar`.